# How can i make a disabled control back to enable using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have done a code to disable a control when user clicks on a control. On my form i am having a `TextBox` and a `DropDown`. When user clicks on a `TextBox` i will `disable` the `DropDown` like that when click on `DropDown` i will disable the `TextBox` which works fine.

But when the user clicks on `Disabled` control i would like to enable that control. Means if i click on `TextBox` which was disabled i would like to `Enable` it like that for `dropdown` too..

My sample Script is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function toggleDropDownList1()
{
var d=document.getElementById("<%= DropDownList4.ClientID %>");
if(d.disabled)
{
d.disabled=false;
}
else
{
 document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
}
}
function toggleDropDownList2()
{
 document.getElementById("<%= DropDownList4.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

Design

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onclick="toggleDropDownList2();"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" onclick="toggleDropDownList1();">
            <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Do you want to enable a disabled control by clicking on that disabled control?? I assume the onclick event dosen't fire on disabled controls?

Comment: Yeah exactly i need that

Comment: warp it with a div, and get the divs onlick to enable it back.

Comment: Hi `Aristos` can i have a piece of code on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The idea is to place a div in front of dropdown list, and this div accept the onclick event**.

The issue here is that the div can not place so easy in front of dropdown list. To place it you need to do that dynamically and use the absolut position.

I make here a small code, and test it and working. I have left the background color RED on div to see where it is. Some details I left it to you, eg to find the width and height of your control list, I place the onclick, you can place back the double click, And just remove the red background.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDropDownList1()
{
    var MyDiv = document.getElementById("DivForClick");
    MyDiv.style.display = "none";

    var d=document.getElementById("<%= DropDownList4.ClientID %>");
    if(d.disabled)
    {
        d.disabled=false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
    }
}

function toggleDropDownList2()
{
    document.getElementById("<%= DropDownList4.ClientID %>").disabled = true;

    var MyDdl = document.getElementById("<%= DropDownList4.ClientID %>");
    var MyDiv = document.getElementById("DivForClick");

    MyDiv.style.display = "block";
    MyDiv.style.left = MyDdl.style.left;
    MyDiv.style.top = MyDdl.style.top;

    // need to find the height/width
    // MyDiv.style.height = MyDdl.style.height;
    // MyDiv.style.width = MyDdl.style.width;   
}
</script>
```

and the asp code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onclick="toggleDropDownList2();"></asp:TextBox>

<br /><br />

<div id="DivForClick" onclick="toggleDropDownList1();" style="z-index:999;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;height:20px;width:40px;background-color:Red;display:none;">
</div>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" onclick="toggleDropDownList1();" style="z-index:2;">
   <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: but on clicking `textbox` didn't enable again

Comment: @User I make it only for drop down list box - the hard one, but you get the idea, you can fix it for the rest, or for all your elements... I give you the idea, I also give you some code that you ask ! but dont ask to work for you.

Comment: `Aristos` can you check my post once

Comment: @User I must tell you that I havent time to help more because of very critical issues that runs here on my company right now, the last week.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently Firefox, and perhaps other browsers, disable DOM events on form fields that are disabled, and any event that starts at the disabled form field is completely canceled and does not propagate up the DOM tree.

So, if you want to achieve something like that, you will probably have to do it with a workaround.

Instead of actually disabling the field try to style the fields to look as if they are disabled, that way you can still capture the click event.

Comment: You might also need a hidden field marking which are disabled so that server side it will know. I think this is probably a good way to go but disabled elements don't post their values to the server whereas with this they will start to do so...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
function toggleIt() {
  var d=document.getElementById("<%= DropDownList4.ClientID %>");
  var t =document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");
  d.disabled=!d.disabled
  t.disabled=!t.disabled
}

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onclick="toggleIt();"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" disabled="disabled" onclick="toggleIt();">
        <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: When clicking on `Dropdown` i am uanble to `enable` it again